# AFNetworking calling clearAuthorizationHeader

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I see this method in AFNetworking:

```
- (void)clearAuthorizationHeader {
    [self.mutableHTTPRequestHeaders removeObjectForKey:@"Authorization"];
}
```

how would I call this method in another file? I tried the following:

```
#import "AFURLRequestSerialization.h"
AFHTTPRequestSerializer *clear;
```

and then calling it inside my logout method like so:

```
[clear.clearAuthorizationHeader];
```

but I get this error:

```
/Users/jsuske/Documents/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/ViewControllers/LHLoginController.m:495:36: Expected identifier
```

Comment: You will first need in the instance of the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` on which you want to clear the authorization headers. Since the method only clears if on it ons instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a method, you need the space notation instead of a Dot. But you need also a valid object instance of the serializer, which you can get from the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Here is an example code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestSerializer <AFURLRequestSerialization> * requestSerializer = manager.requestSerializer;
[requestSerializer clearAuthorizationHeader];
```